# Saving a table range in Excel as PDF

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to export predefined excel table ranges (those from Excel 2007 & 2010) as PDF. Only the specific table should appear in the PDF, not the whole sheet.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like:

```
Sheet1.Range("B2:B7").ExportAsFixedFormat xlTypePDF, "C:\My Documents\Test.pdf"
```

Comment: Well, it exports the whole sheet including the whitespace. But unless there is a VBA internal solution I can handle it using pdfcrop.

Comment: This worked for me! I have been pulling my hair out trying to use Range("S26:X46").Select followed by ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs with PublishOption:=xlSelection. Thanks, I can go to bed now.